# Nokia HERE Route Match Extension Api

Tags: routes, match, here-api

I am trying to use Nokias GPS Match API, but i am facing always with same error.

Error: Invalid character in parameter: ' '

gpx File in Attachment.[My Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMsZr.png)

Here is constructed URL :

> http://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id={}&app_code={}&routemode=car&file=UEsDBBQAAAAIAOd6QUpfY6VcVQEAAB4EAAAOAAAAR1BTX1JlYWxfMi5ncHiNk0tvwjAMx89D4jtU
>   va95OE9UypELk5C4cK1YV6rRh5po7cdfCJtEDqg52Un8i/O3nXw3t7fkpxpN03fblGQ43RXrVV4P
>   c7i7XrnAzmxm02zTq7XDBqFpmrIJsn6sEcWYoPPH4XS5Vm353nTGlt2l+scCxPZDX4/lVzNnl75F
>   ++MZEeQzmGZj/AWH/lJan3uRS/4i1qvXMcjJyWbzmd6l2fHbmSTJu7Ktiv3xlCPv+T13aKra+4/V
>   YJNbabcpU5nWTBLKmEqT2/1pKgPJMAAWOi1y5INfkwyAByBmjMeAEpR4AkFLpjRfBhVmoAKQcQAS
>   AYICqgOSMEVYBCmpEEFOpQiPyamxDB+rmKAsQqUTRVhIYo05jSClDgsrJVFcLYIcE4VJAAIXZLmV
>   HHMuRVBYiTEFGUFq14NApRAQ0RFO4F7FZ44KNxjP4Fvi/cfYe9db92WKX1BLAQIUABQAAAAIAOd6
>   QUpfY6VcVQEAAB4EAAAOAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAABHUFNfUmVhbF8yLmdweFBLBQYAAAAAAQAB
>   ADwAAACBAQAAAAA=

I would be glad, if anyone help me 
Thanks

Comment: For one, I see a space inside your url between "&file=" and "base64". Did you try changing that?

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that.

Comment: We (HERE) provides new location related APIs, SDKs, tools and solutions. For your use case you need to take a look at Geocoder API: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html Please look at our developer portal for other products: https://developer.here.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new HERE Fleet Telematics API to make this request using the GPX file and an apiKey:

```
curl
--request POST
-H "Content-Type: application/binary"
--data-binary "@C:\temp\trace001.gpx"
"https://m.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/matchroute.json?routemode=car&apiKey{YOUR_API_KEY}"
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/dev_guide/topics/example-gpx-trace.html